# How to write logging into SharePoint event to the external system?

Tags: events, sharepoint-2010, authentication, system, external

I need to write events to the external database when users logging into SharePoint - username and datetime nothing else.

I use Claims authentication(Windows and forms) and standard login page.

I need to retrieve IIS logs or is there any easier way?

Thanks in advance, Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create my own login page.  There is a good article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/07/09/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx) that describes how to do this.  Include a method in your custom page to override the submit event for the page.  You will have to handle the authentication logic, but once the user is authenticated, you can call your external system to log the information.

Note that the custom login page is defined for the entire web application.  Any other site collections on this web application will get this same login when authenticating.